# Decoding a file created with the filesystem API

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have images uploaded to the blobstore using filesystem API. The files have been uploaded successfully and I can see the blobs in the respective directory.

But then, how do I decode these files such that when sent back to the client or retrieved using the blobstore API, I'm able to get an image? Right now /blobstore/writable:xxx is not useful for me because when I wrap the path in `<img src="/blobstore/writable:xxx" />`, it doesn't give me an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed with this:

```
    FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
    AppEngineFile writableFile = fileService.createNewBlobFile(request.getParameter("qqfile"));
    FileWriteChannel writeChannel = null;
        try {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; // 4MB
                lock = true;
                writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(writableFile, lock);
                // increase the buffer size as you are reading from the 
                // input stream. Read the input stream into buffer
                for (int n; (n = stream.read(buffer)) != -1; ){ 
                    writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer));
                } 
            } finally {
                    writeChannel.closeFinally();
            }

    BlobKey blobKey = fileService.getBlobKey(writableFile);
    ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();

    // produces something like http://localhost:8888/_ah/img/SU52WMsoCRP3kqAvQqVW3g
    String imageUrl = imagesService.getServingUrl(blobKey);
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options -

1. Use [getServingUrl](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/images/ImagesService.html#getServingUrl(com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobKey)) to create a URL to your image, and then return that URL as part of your response. Store this URL in the datastore as the URL will not change for the same blob. This also lets you dynamically resize and crop the image that you're serving. The URLs are public so if you want some form of access control over serving the image you might want option (2).
2. Use [serveBlob](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html#Serving_a_Blob) and a request handler to send the images. No dynamic resizing (you can do it yourself in the handler if you want) but you can ACL each request if that's required.

Comment: On 1, I do not intend to store the image in the blobstore. Instead I'm using the filesystem API. But I'm an exception while doing that: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to read image`. Do you have any idea about what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: FYI filesystem API stores blobs in either blobstore or google storage. You need to generate a blobkey from the stored object.